# Embiggening a graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I'm making a bunch of line graphs in R with ggplot2 and I want to save them as jpegs.  However, I would like to make the graphs bigger or higher resolution, so that if you zoom in on the graphs when viewing them they don't look so pixelated.

Here's a code snippet:

```
library("ggplot2")

p <- ggplot(df1)

p <- p +
  geom_line(aes(time, ee_amt, colour="ee_amt"), size = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(time, ee_amt, colour="ee_amt"), size = 2)

jpeg("G:\\Auto Parts\\sample.jpg")
  print(p)
dev.off()
```

Comment: + 1 for the Jebediah Springfield (Simpsons) reference!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `ggsave` and specify the `dpi` you desire.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
my_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(size = 4)
ggsave(my_plot, file="sample.jpg", dpi = 600)
```

Comment: I'd also suggest using something other than a `jpg`, as this is a lossy format. perhaps `png`, or `svg`, `pdf` or `postscript` (or even `tikz`) if you want vectorized graphics, where the zooming won't be an issue.

Comment: Great, thanks.  For some reason this won't work with 600 dpi (I get this an error message that goes "Error in grDevices::Unable to start device").  But I changed it to 300 dpi and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Save plots as PostScript, and use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) `convert` to convert to JPEG at the desired density, e.g.:

```
ggsave(my_plot, file="foo.ps")
```

Then, to make a 300 dpi JPEG version:

```
$ convert foo.ps -density 300 foo.jpeg
```

You'll have a smaller file that you can render at any resolution you want and any bitmap format that ImageMagick supports.

If this is for the web, consider converting to SVG or PDF formats:

```
$ convert foo.ps foo.svg
```

You can embed SVG in an `iframe` pretty easily, and this facilitates smooth zooming with small file sizes, compared with high-resolution bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend png(): ggsave() or jpeg() are better options. To directly control the resolution with png(), use:

```
library("ggplot2")

p <- ggplot(df1)

p <- p +
geom_line(aes(time, ee_amt, colour="ee_amt"), size = 2) + 
geom_point(aes(time, ee_amt, colour="ee_amt"), size = 2)

W = 1680
H = 1050

png("test.png", width = W, height = H)
print(p)
graphics.off()
```

The same should work for jpeg().